# Best technique to convert pdf into image

Tags: pdf, pdf-conversion

I am converting pdf into images in php using imagick , but it was too slow then i used pdf.js on client side to convert pdf into images but pdf.js is not supported on mobile devices, I run this on iphone 8 plus and it is not working , any suggestion which technique could b fastest to convert pdf in to image in php or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason PDF rasterization should be done on the server side and not the client side.  It is an incredibly difficult task.  It can depend on different factors like the resolution and color space of the target image. It also depends on how complex the PDF input is and the quality of the PDF software.  I'm afraid there is no one size fits all answer.